# XML Serialization woes in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, xml-serialization

Here's my class:

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRootAttribute("Language")]
    public class Language : ISerializable
    {
        string Id {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Part2B {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Part2T {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Part1 {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Scope {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string LanguageType {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string RefName {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Comment {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

snipped

I'm returning an array of them from a Mono web service, like this:

```
[WebMethod()]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public Language[] GetLanguages()
        {
            List<Language> languages;
            languages = GetLanguageList();
            return languages.ToArray();
        }
```

But what I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfLanguage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Language />
  <Language />
  <Language />
  <Language />
</ArrayOfLanguage>
```

Why are the members not getting serialized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your properties are not public.
XmlSerialization [only serialises public fields and properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

> XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public properties and fields to a serial format

The [default accessibility for fields and properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) (indeed all members) is **private** in c#.

Also implementing ISerializable has no effect on XmlSerialization (that would be [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)).
Neither does the [Serializable] attribute, instead you need [one or more of these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: :) It's a horrid mix to a hangover

Comment: Nor does `[Serializable]` ;-p

Comment: I was throwing the kitchen sink at it to get it to work :) Thanks, gang, you're lifesavers :)